# Можно в заголовке объединить две колонки QT?

Tags: c++, qt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Можно сделать таблицу как на рисунке?

Объединить две колонки в одну "дней", "месяцев" в "Временной период" в шапке. И добавлять значения если указано кол. дней и месяцев в каждую соответствующую ячейку, если указано до настоящего времени объединять колонку дней и мес. в одну и добавлять строчку : "н.в." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

стандартный заголовок в Qt не позволяет объединять столбцы. Попробуйте использовать сторонее решение (например HierarchicalHeaderView  https://store.kde.org/p/1132194/)